# Firebase Storage: encrypting video files?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I want to use firebase functions to encrypt a video file after it has been uploaded using cryptography (AES or other.....). I don't know from where to start. In android it is possible to use `cipher` class to encrypt the video file using AES on the client side. But I don't want client side I want to do the exact same encryption on firebase storage, I guess I need a firebase function for that that listens to uploads in storage. Any tutorial or docs on this?